# Компилятор не поддерживает расширенную инициализацию

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, инициализация

Имеется такой код:

```
int main() {
    double d {4.5};
    int x {d};
}
```

Прочитал, что в новой версии *С++11* есть поддержка на запрет сужающих преобразований при инициализации. Но компилятор ошибки не выдает, хотя должен (ибо я пытаюсь `double` в `int` преобразовать с синтаксисом новой версии инициализации (с помощью фигурных скобок), которая как раз запрещает подобные небезопасные преобразования.

IDE - DevC++ 5.11
Компилятор - TDM-GCC 4.9.2.

**Вопрос:** Так почему нет поддержки этой новой инициализации? Компилятор новый же, его вместе со средой скачал недавно вот.

Comment: Выдает [предупреждение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MT418d7lcmVXHFX0). При соответствующих ключах даст ошибку. Собственно вот и с [ошибкой](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8bkYL3AnDcovtINn) тот же код. `-pedantic-errors` добавил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандарт С++ не обязывает реализацию языка выдавать именно "ошибку компиляции" для случаев когда в стандарте написано что код ошибочен. (Однако при этом не должно ломается SFINAE, иначе это уже баг компилятора).

Компилятор g++ в некоторых случаях ограничивается предупреждением:

```
double d = 4.5;
int x{d};  // предупреждение в g++
int y{4.5};  // ошибка в g++
```

Впрочем этого достаточно, т.к. рекомендуется компилировать код с `-Wall -pedantic -Werror`.

Что касается стандарта, то `int x{d};` это несомненно неправильный код. В разделе `[dcl.init.list]` есть [аналогичный пример](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7).